# Backbone.JS Trigger & On - Getting Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am trying to create a Backbone app where people can choose between different ingredients and sizes and  finally get a recipe view with a description (defined in JSON) to create their own pizza.

I have 2 views : the `IngredientView` and `RecipeView`. I want to trigger an event from the `IngredientView` to the `RecipeView`. But when I reload `Index.html` I get an error *"cannot read property on of undefined"*.

**Ingredient.js**

```
site.views.Ingredient = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'p',

    events: {
        "click p": "ingredientClicked" 
    },

    initialize: function(properties){
        this.ingredientTemplate = properties.ingredientTemplate;
        console.log("Pizza Ingredienten View is mooi geladen!");
        this.loadListOfIngredients();
    },

    ingredientClicked: function(e){
        var chosenIngredient = $(e.currentTarget).data('ingredient');
        site.events.trigger("chosenIngredient", {ingredient: chosenIngredient});
    },

    loadListOfIngredients: function(){
        this.collection.fetch({
            success: _.bind(this.loadIngredientSuccessHandler, this),
            error: _.bind(this.loadIngredientErrorHandler, this)
        });
    },

    loadIngredientSuccessHandler: function(collection, ingredienten, options){
      for (var i= 0; i < ingredienten.length; i++){
          data = {
              ingredientName: ingredienten[i]['name'],
              ingredientSort: ingredienten[i]['sort']
          };

        element ($el).
          var template = _.template(this.ingredientTemplate.html(), data, this);
          this.$el.append(template);
          console.log(data);
      }
    },
    loadIngredientErrorHandler: function(collection, response, options){
        console.log("Er is iets fout gegaan met het JSON bestand")
    }
});
```

**Recipe View**

```
site.views.RecipeView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function(properties){
       console.log("Recepten View is ook mooi geladen!")
       this.recipeTemplate = properties.recipeTemplate;
       site.events.on("chosenIngredient", this.chosenIngredient, this);
    },

    chosenIngredient: function(data){
        this.ingredient = data.ingredient;

        this.checkIfChosen();
    },

    checkIfChosen: function(){
            this.collection.fetch({
                success: _.bind(this.successHandler, this),
                error: _.bind(this.errorHandler)
            })
    },

    successHandler: function(collection, response, options){
        if (this.ingredient == "Mozarella"){
            console.log("Lekker Mozarellatje hoor!")
        }

        var template = _.template(this.recipeTemplate.html(), templateData, this);
        this.$el.html(template);

    }

});
```

Comment: Ho do you define `site.events`? And `element ($el).` in `loadIngredientSuccessHandler`is probably out of place.

Comment: I am making use of a init.js file

`(function () {
    window.site = {};
    site.views = {};
    site.$document = $(document);
    site.models = {};
    site.collections = {};

    site.events = _.clone(Backbone.events);
})()`

Comment: Backbone.Events , with a capital E at Events

Comment: That one did the trick.. but after changing that i can log my Ingredient (in the console) but receive another error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined `